# Decoding PKCS7 SMIME data using C#

Tags: c#, openssl, smime

I am encrypting data using openssl using the following

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in data.json -aes256 certificate.pem
```

data.json contents:

```
{"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}
```

ending up with:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; 
name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

I'm looking for a way to decrypt using the private key (PEM file) in C#
however, everything i've found is half baked / no proper documentation or examples

Any ideas? recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem is that S/MIME needs to encrypt a MIME entity, not content data. In other words, you first need to add MIME headers such as a Content-Type header and potentially others if you decide to base64 encode the json data (e.g. Content-Transfer-Encoding).

For example:

```
Content-Type: text/json

{"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}
```

Once you've done that, using [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit), you could do this to decrypt it:

```
var pkcs7 = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime) MimeEntity.Load (stream);
MimePart mime;

using (ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext ()) {
    mime = (MimePart) pkcs7.Decrypt (ctx);
}

using (var content = new MemoryStream ()) {
    mime.Content.DecodeTo (content);

    // now your raw json data is contained in the `content` stream.
}
```